# Add border to Relative Layout at run time in Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to add border from all sides to my `RelativeLayout` at runtime. I am able to get the border, however it is changing the background color of the layout. If I set the background color to `white`, it is also changing the border color to white. How do I avoid that?

Here is my code below:

```
private static void drawBorder(Context context, View layout){

    final RectShape rect = new RectShape();
    final ShapeDrawable rectShapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(rect);

    final Resources res = context.getResources();

    final Paint paint = rectShapeDrawable.getPaint();
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(rectShapeDrawable); //Testing on phone with API < 16

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an xml file with the following border description

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
  android:radius="2dp"
  android:topRightRadius="0dp"
  android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
  android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
<stroke
  android:width="1dp"
  android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

and set backgroundresource for the view with this drawable

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your method however, it is drawing the border, but changing the background color of the layout to Gray. The same as I was getting in the code above.

Comment: set the fill color to transparent

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
private static Bitmap drawBitmapWithBorders(int width, int height, int borderWidth,
                                     int backgroundColor, int borderColor){
    int pixels[] = new int[width*height];
    Arrays.fill(pixels, borderColor);
    for(int i=borderWidth;i<height-borderWidth;i++){
        Arrays.fill(pixels, i*width+borderWidth, (i+1)*width-borderWidth, backgroundColor);
    }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```